# Are CakePHP models actually controllers?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, laravel

I am no expert in the **MVC** architecture, however I have been working using the mentioned architecture on some JAVA projects. Now I'm getting into `PHP` `MVC` Frameworks, (like **CakePHP and Laravel**) and I decided to go for **CakePHP**.

Going deep into it, I see Models in **CakePHP** are in charge of operations like querying and some others while **data** itself is managed in `arrays` (i.e. $user['User']['first_name']).

The way I am familiar with, **Model** classes are just for storing model data, in other words, what arrays do in **CakePHP**

```
public Class User {
    private String firstName;
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public String getFirstName() { return this.firstName; }
}
```

And **Controller** classes are in charge of querying and other model-building operation, in other words, what models do in **CakePHP**:

```
public Class UserManager {
    public User getById(int id) { /* */ }
    public boolean save(User user) { /*  */ }
}
```

So, are **CakePHP**, and simillar `MVC Frameworks`, Models actually controllers? also if yes, shouldn't this be a new type of architecture, something like Router-View-Controller, since controller class actually routes request ?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html

Comment: Actually the pattens they implement should be called: *Template-Logic-ORM*, because only thing from MVC thay have taken are "names".

Comment: This is exactly the kind of discussion I wanted with the question. I agree with you, only MVC thing they have are the "names". So.. Template-Logic-ORM, never heard of it, could you describe it for me please? (:

Answer (score 0):

I think [the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html) explains it already pretty well:

> Models are the classes that sit as the business layer in your
>   application. This means that they should be responsible for managing
>   almost everything that happens regarding your data, its validity,
>   interactions and evolution of the information workflow in your domain
>   of work.
>
> Usually model classes represent data and are used in CakePHP
>   applications for data access, more specifically they represent a
>   database table but they are not limited to this, but can be used to
>   access anything that manipulates data such as files, external web
>   services, iCal events, or rows in a CSV file.

Actually a model in CakePHP 2.0 is basically thought to do any kind of data manipulation.

- Need to turn an array into a CSV string? Model job.
- Need to validate an uploaded image? Model job.
- Need to save an uploaded file? Model job.
- Need to somehow manipulate your POST data? Model job.
- ...

None of the tasks above is thought to be done in a controller, we want to respect separation of concerns (SoC). The controller just manages the request but *doesn't* process data, that's the models job. Also models are more easy to unit test than controllers plus you can share them in a shell, you cant do that with controllers without MVC violations: Here is an example:

**You should always keep your models fat and controllers thin:**

```
/** CONTROLLER **/

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Model->doSomething($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something was done right!'));
        $this->redirect(['view' => $this->Model->data['Model']['id']); 
    }
}

/** MODEL **/

public function doSomething($data) {
   $this->create();
   $result = $this->save($data);
   if ($result) {
       $result[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey] = $this->getLastInsertId();
       $this->data = $result;
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

No, models are not controllers, not in any php framework out there.

Models just present a collection of your data, a controller at the other hand controls the flow between models and view. For example, the controller calls your model to get data, then process that somehow and push to to the view, so you can pick it up there and do something with it.

Are you willing to tell why you choosed for cakePHP ?

Comment: I picked CakePHP for no reason at all, I just happen to hear of it. Also, <a href="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html">in this link</a> you can see a Model definition. It doesn't take any querying operation, it is basically a data-holder.

Comment: Well that is correct, a model actually holds your data. For example in Laravel (the one you did not picked) you get all your users out of your database like this.... $users = User::all() which will return all your user records. User is the model here, all() is a function of that model and it is buld-in so that you do not have to worry about it. I guess cakePHP behaves exactly the same.

Comment: In that case, all() would be a controller function: UserManager.getAll(); which returns a List of Users (that are models)

Comment: Yeah if you say so, i have no exprience with cakePHP at all, but i guess you could be right there. In laravel all is a function from the model that you call in your controller. So it is not that different with cakePHP i guess.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco "a List of Users (that are models)" That's wrong. A single record is an "Entity" and a set of Entities is usually  handled in something like a ResultSet which implements an interator. CakePHP 3.0 does it this way and I think other frameworks do it similar. There is an "Entity" plugin for Cake2 that returns your results as objects by the way. Models are *not* data objects. I down-voted the answer as well because it's not true that a model "just present a collection of your data".

Comment: Hey it's ok man, i don't blame you. From the laravel docs... The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. So hey if you understand all that, that is ok man, that is why i am here, to learn too. I just tell it as i would say, because for me that model is a collection of data. So i explained it in my own words for the best i could. What i does all on the background, i don't know. So my excuses my answer was wrong.

Comment: By the way, above is stated... You should always keep your models fat and controllers thin: well i have gone through a few programming lessons recently and they just say the opposite or at least something complete different. You should keep your models thin, create repositories and let services do the hard work. So you see, there are so many oppinions in coding-land, but WHO is actually correct ?